# Как сохранить http-response в MemoryStream или Jpeg файл

Tags: c#

В общем сабжю Посмотрел много форумов. Предлагают `Webclient`. Я хочу через `HttpWebrequest`.

Comment: @herberus: А что вы пробовали? Покажите код. Что не удалось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
var request = HttpWebrequest.Create(url);
using (var response = request.GetResponse()) 
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
 var memStream = new MemoryStream();
 responseStream.CopyTo(memStream);
}
```